# codeigniter $this->image_lib->resize() function not resizing image

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, resize

i want to resize image, but it not working properly, $this->image_lib->resize()  this function can not resize image. it produce orginal image size. i am upload 600*600  size image. but i want to resize 300*300
please check my code below.

```
if( $this->input->post('save')){

        $config['upload_path'] = 'images';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = 1000;
        $config['overwrite'] = false;
        $config['encrypt_name'] = true;
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        $this->upload->initialize($config);

        if(!$this->upload->do_upload('user_image')){
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $this->upload->display_errors());
            $this->load->view('create',$data);
            return;
        }else{
            $upicture = $this->upload->data();
            $image_data = $upicture;
            $config2['image_library'] = 'gd2';
            $config2['source_image'] = $image_data['full_path']; //get original image
            $config2 ['new_image'] = 'images'; //save as new image //need to create thumbs first
            $config2 ['maintain_ratio'] = false;
            $config2 ['create_thumb'] = false;
            $config2 ['overwrite'] = false;
            $config2['width'] = 300;
            $config2['height'] = 300;
            $this->load->library('image_lib', $config2);
            $this->image_lib->resize();

            $img_name = $upicture['file_name'];
        }


        $this->form_validation->set_rules('student_name', 'Student Name','required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('student_email', 'Student Email','required|valid_email|is_unique[std_info.std_email]',['is_unique'=> 'The {field} field is alredy exits']);

        $this->form_validation->set_message('valid_email','This {field} field is invalid');
        //$this->form_validation->set_message('is_unique', 'This {field} is Alreay exist!');


        $receive = $this->input->post(['student_name','student_email','student_about'], TRUE);
        $param = [
            'std_name'  => (string) $receive['student_name'],
            'std_email' => (string) $receive['student_email'],
            'std_about' => (string) $receive['student_about'],
            'images'    => $img_name
        ];
        if($this->form_validation->run()){
            $response = $this->std_model->insert_data('std_info',$param);
            if($response['status'] === 'success'){
                redirect('welcome');
            }
        }else{
            $this->load->view('create',$data);
            return;
        }

    }
```

Comment: You need to explain exactly where in your code that it is not giving you the expected result.

Comment: $config2['width'] = 300;
            $config2['height'] = 300;

Comment: Set overwrite to true as you just want the resized image right?

Comment: ... If so you should remove new image as per documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If neither of the two preferences listed above (create_thumb, and
>   new_image) are used, the resizing method will instead target the
>   original image for processing.

I tested your code and as to my suspicions, you should do the following:

```
$config2['image_library'] = 'gd2';
$config2['source_image'] = $image_data['full_path']; //get original image
//$config2 ['new_image'] = 'images'; //save as new image //need to create thumbs first
$config2 ['maintain_ratio'] = false;
$config2 ['create_thumb'] = false;
//$config2 ['overwrite'] = true;
$config2['width'] = 300;
$config2['height'] = 300;
```

> From the documentation on Creating a Copy: "The resizing method will create a copy of the
>   image file (and preserve the original) **if** you set a path and/or a
>   new filename using this preference"

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/image_lib.html

If you want to keep the original and have a thumb, either make a new name for the file in the `new_image` field as in 'images/someimage.jpg' or set `create_thumb` as `TRUE`.

---

### Refactor

I would also highly suggest refactoring your logic. Assuming form validation fails you will left with a lot of orphaned images as every post makes a new image (and you are not overwriting or have known filenames). So first do form validation, then upload, then add to database:

```
if ($this->input->post('save')) {
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('student_name', 'Student Name', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('student_email', 'Student Email', 'required|valid_email|is_unique[std_info.std_email]', ['is_unique' => 'The {field} field is alredy exits']);
    $this->form_validation->set_message('valid_email', 'This {field} field is invalid');
    if (!$this->form_validation->run()) {
        $this->load->view('create', $data);
        return;
    }
    $config['upload_path'] = 'images';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = 1000;
    $config['overwrite'] = false;
    $config['encrypt_name'] = true;
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->upload->initialize($config);
    if (!$this->upload->do_upload('user_image')) {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $this->upload->display_errors());
        $this->load->view('create', $data);
        return;
    }
    $image_data = $this->upload->data();
    $config2['image_library'] = 'gd2';
    $config2['source_image'] = $image_data['full_path']; //get original image
    //$config2['new_image'] = 'images'; //save as new image //need to create thumbs first
    $config2['maintain_ratio'] = false;
    $config2['create_thumb'] = false;
    //$config2['overwrite'] = false;
    $config2['width'] = 300;
    $config2['height'] = 300;
    $this->load->library('image_lib', $config2);
    if (!$this->image_lib->resize()) {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $this->image_lib->display_errors());
        $this->load->view('create', $data);
        return;
    }
    $receive = $this->input->post(['student_name', 'student_email', 'student_about'], TRUE);
    $param = [
        'std_name' => (string) $receive['student_name'],
        'std_email' => (string) $receive['student_email'],
        'std_about' => (string) $receive['student_about'],
        'images' => $image_data['file_name']
    ];
    $response = $this->std_model->insert_data('std_info', $param);
    if ($response['status'] === 'success') {
        redirect('welcome');
    }
}
```